# authentication error during VSTS hosted build

Tags: azure-devops

I set up hosted VS2017 build for "Project1" repo under my https://XXX1.visualstudio.com VSTS account.
This repo references a submodule "Project2" that has been setup under different VSTS account to which I have full admin permissions. https://XXX2.visualstudio.com
When I run VSTS hosted build for my top level "Project1" repo I get authentication error while cloning "Project2" submodule. However I have no issue cloning submodule manually in Git client on my pc. Getting following error.

> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://XXX2.visualstudio.com':
>   terminal prompts disabled   fatal: clone of
>   'https://XXX2.visualstudio.com/Projects/.../Project2' into submodule
>   path 'D:/a/1/s/Project2' failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even you adding/cloning the submodule repo `project2` from local pc, you should input your credential for the first time.

So you should **provide your credential for cloning the submodule repo `Project2`** in VSTS build:

#### First, make sure you have alternate credential for your VSTS account1 (https://XXX1.visualstudio.com)

In Alternate authentication credentials tab (https://XXX1.visualstudio.com/_details/security/altcreds), add sscondary user name and password if you not have:

[image]

#### Then, add the alternate credential for submodule `Project2` repo (which outside your VSTS account1)

In your Project1 repo, there has the file `.gitmodules` to record the submodule repo `Project2`, the content likes:

```
[submodule "Project2"]
    path = Project2
    url = https://account2.visualstudio.com/projects/_git/Project2
```

Then add the alternate credential in the submodule URL, the format as:

```
[submodule "Project2"]
    path = Project2
    url = https://<secondary username>:<secondary password>@account2.visualstudio.com/projects/_git/Project2
```

Such as the URL should be `https://myuser:password@myaccount.visualstudio.com/project/_git/repo` correspondingly with the example as the picture above.

Besides, there has an user voice [Build support for external submodules that require authentication](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/11462817-build-support-for-external-submodules-that-require) which request has the way to get external git submodule in build definition, you can vote and follow up.

Comment: That worked. Thank you, Marina so much for helping me. Are you sure I cannot use acces tokens in my setup? I'm not sure how much I want to get in to the business of managing credentials for multiple users and keep hardcoded passwords out in the open.

Comment: Personal access token can not be recognized in the url format. If there are multiple user can access Project1 repo or the build definition, your alternate credential will surely exposed. The workaround is **import the Project2 repo into your own VSTS account1**, then treat the imported Project2 as submodule, then it's unnecessary to add credential in .gitmodules since the imported repo in the same account as the main repo Project1.

Comment: I also thought about importing a repo over to account1 But this means cloning the module and keeping two copies of the same code which is a maintenance headache. Is there any way to direct VSTS to use already authenticated Windows credentials for account2?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no other ways for now. But there has similar request for this feature in the user voice https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/11462817-build-support-for-external-submodules-that-require. And you can vote and follow up.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Solunds like alternative credentials feature is my best friend for a while.